# Load CSV file in Redis using Redis-cli on Windows

Tags: java, redis, redis-server

I went through questions like [how to import a ".csv " data-file into the Redis database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840707/how-to-import-a-csv-data-file-into-the-redis-database) and decided to put a question here after lot of web searching.

I've an `employee.csv` file and looking to import that file using the `redis-cli`. I am using the Windows version `3.2.100` of Redis server.

employee.csv

```
SET "employee_1" "1, John Smith, 40, Male, John, 10000"
SET "employee_2" "2, Marco Polo, 43, Male, Marco, 10000"
....
SET "employee_1999999" "1999999, Tom Cruse, 50, Male, Tom, 10001"
```

I also followed url: https://gist.github.com/arsperger/6f246f21279edf3cd03ba2bee19daaef and https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26357.htm, but cat will not support to the Windows version.

What can I try next?

Comment: You could either use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) or use Windows ports of specific tools like "awk" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows

Comment: @ Tomasz Poradowski - I used GIT bash, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Also cygwin seems not working. Could you please try and guide us? Many Thanks sir in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance when you use mentioned "Git Bash" you can do as follows (last step outputs the commands, but they may as well be piped to `redis-cli`:

[image: Converting simple CSV to SET commands for Redis]

The above comes from Git 2.17.1 for Windows. The final command-line is:

```
tail -n +2 test.csv | awk -F',' '{print "SET \""$1"\" \""$0"\""}' | redis-cli
```

Please note a couple of assumptions:

- Strings in CSV are not enclosed in double quotes - if so you'd have to escape them when outputting "SET" commands
- First line in CSV contains headers and values are separated with a comma.

Comment: We're getting below error. Bash will never be able to understand `redis-cli.exe`
```$ tail -n +2 test.csv | awk -F',' '{print "SET \""$1"\" \""$0"\""}' | redis-cli
bash: redis-cli: command not found```

Comment: @PAA either use full path like `/c/Program\ Files/Redis/redis-cli` or change the PATH variable via `export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Redis`